# Should I get a BSc at a top-ranked university or a MComp at a lower-ranked university?

Tags: computer-science, united-kingdom

I'm currently in the situation of having to choose between the two options aforementioned in the title. The field of study I look forward to pursue is Computer Science. I would say that attending a course which offers a MComp would provide me with a deeper knowledge and a more elaborate skillset which I can employ after I finish my studies. However, I also have the option of pursuing a BSc at a top-ranked university which would probably provide me a higher-quality education. Moreover, the difference regarding rank (and supposedly quality) between the two universities is not *big* (namely, only a few places).

To sum up, which path should I choose for my academic preparation ?

Comment: Do you already have a BSc?

Comment: No, I'm finishing highschool this year.

Comment: Would you please explain what you mean by _to choose between the two options_? Don't you have to have BSc before you are offered a choice of MComp?

Comment: As far as I know, I'm not required to have a BSc in order to apply for a MComp.  "BSc Computer Science consists of three years of academic study, whereas the MComp consists of four years of study. Both are undergraduate courses, but MComp is a Masters-level qualification. "

Comment: Personally, I would choose the university that has the course *that I want to do*.  Unless it's truly a world-famous university, nobody will care in the long run which one you go to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can attend a top university, do so.  Having other excellent students around can provide a much better learning environment--to the point that in three years at a top place you may learn as much as in four years at a more mediocre institution.  If you do well, you can always do another one or two years of graduate study after your bachelor's degree.

Comment: But you trade in time for hat.